# DBeaver SQL Server GO invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

Is there a way to get DBeaver to use SQL Server's alternate "GO" delimiter? Squirrel SQL allows this via a SQL Server preference (statement separator).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

- Open connection editor
- click on "Edit Driver".
- Switch tab on "Adv.
  parameters".
- Set "Script delimiter" value to "go".

[GO batch support](https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/issues/192)

Comment: I don't use DBeaver anymore, however that is I believe how I solved the issue. I don't think it was a complete fix but it worked as a workaround. +1 for linking to my own github issue on the topic lol

Answer (score 4):

@Jonathan's screen seems to not exist anymore with actual version. This works for me :

- Right click on your connection and select "Edit Connection".
- Under SQL Editor -> SQL Processing, click the checkbox for "Datasource settings" and then change the "Statements delimiter" to "GO".

Comment: Confirmed, this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the DBeaver preferences that allows you to specify a delimiter, but it seems to be not working. Whatever gets entered and saved in the preferences is ignored.

[Screen capture of relevant DBeaver preferences pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOWdj.png)

In the meantime, you can always replace all instances of 'GO' in your SQL with a semicolon ';'.